# How to generate a vulnerability status Report from Black Duck using script python (Hub Instance API)

Tags: python, blackduck

I 'm following this github URL to generate a vulnerability status report, including the result of the scan using Black Duck : https://github.com/blackducksoftware/hub-rest-api-python/tree/master
In the examples, there is a Python script to make the generation happen, which is **generate_vuln_status_report.py**
I run this script on my local machine, and it works fine. As a result, I have a zip folder that contains a csv file including the result of the Black Duck, but for all the projects that I have in the Dashboard , I need to adjust this script to make the generation done by project name and project version to be able to filter the csv file generated with the required project.
I adjusted the script by this way :

`
from blackduck.HubRestApi import HubInstance

```
import argparse
import json
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate vulnerability status report for a     
specific project version.")
parser.add_argument("--project_name", required=True, help="Name of the project")
parser.add_argument("--format", default="CSV", choices=["CSV", "JSON"], help="Report format")
parser.add_argument("--tries", type=int, default=3, help="Number of retries")
args = parser.parse_args()


hub = HubInstance()

class FailedReportDownload(Exception):
   pass
def download_report(location, report_format, project_name, retries=args.tries):
report_id = location.split("/")[-1]

if retries:
    print("Retrieving generated report from {}".format(location))
    # response = hub.download_vuln_status_report(location)
    response = hub.execute_get(location)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        if report_format == "CSV":
            download_filename = project_name + ".zip"  # Use project_name instead of filename
        if report_format == "CSV":
            download_filename = filename + ".zip"
            response = hub.execute_get(download_url,  {'Content-Type': 'application/zip'})
        else:
            download_filename = filename + ".json"
            response = hub.execute_get(content_url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            if report_format == "CSV":
                with open(download_filename, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                print("Successfully downloaded zip file to {} for report {}".format(
                    download_filename, report_id))
            else:
                with open(download_filename, "w") as f:
                    json.dump(response.json(), f, indent=3)
                print("Successfully downloaded json report data to {} for report {}".format(
                    download_filename, report_id))
        else:
            print("Failed to retrieve report {}".format(report_id))
            print("Probably not ready yet, waiting 5 seconds then retrying...")
            time.sleep(args.tries)  # Use args.tries instead of args.sleep_time
            retries -= 1
            download_report(location, report_format, filename, retries)
    else:
        print("Failed to find report information at location {}, status code: {}".format(location, response.status_code))
else:
    raise FailedReportDownload("Failed to retrieve report {} after {} retries".format(report_id, args.tries))

 project_name = args.project_name
 version_name = args.version_name  # Update this to the version you need
 report_format = args.format
 response = hub.create_vuln_status_report(project_name, version_name, format=report_format)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Successfully created vulnerability status report")
    location = response.headers['Location']
    download_report(location, args.format, args.project_name)  # Pass project_name instead of 
    file_name
else:
   print("Failed to create vulnerability status report, status code returned: 
   {}".format(response.status_code))`
```

Also I updated the used function like this :

```
def create_vuln_status_report(self, project_name, version_name, format="CSV"):
assert format in HubInstance.valid_vuln_status_report_formats, "Format must be one of {}".format(HubInstance.valid_vuln_status_report_formats)

project = self.get_project_by_name(project_name)

if project:
    version = self.get_version_by_name(project, version_name)
    if version:
        post_data = {
            "reportFormat": format,
            "locale": "en_US",
            "project": project['_meta']['href'],
            "version": version['_meta']['href']
        }
        url = self.get_apibase() + "/vulnerability-status-reports"
        custom_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.blackducksoftware.report-4+json',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.blackducksoftware.report-4+json'
        }
        return self.execute_post(url, custom_headers=custom_headers, data=post_data)
    else:
        print("Version '{}' not found in project '{}'.".format(version_name, project_name))
        return None
else:
    print("Project '{}' not found.".format(project_name))
    return None
```

I found this error :

3`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Yasmine.Omrane\Desktop\source-scans\report.py", line 70, in <module> response = hub.create_vuln_status_report(project_name, version_name, format=report_format) TypeError: create_vuln_status_report() got multiple values for argument 'format'3`

Any idea about the error , or I should update it by another way .
I need to generate the report for the specefic project with the specefic version.
Any advice please

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: The edit of my post is well done